# Circuit breaker problem

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have a circuit breaker box and when wiring two 120 breakers one will read 0 and the other will jump up to 240. What can be causing the full 240 volts from the pole to go directly into a 120 circuit breaker?

Totally confused and frustrated that no one knows why.
Help please

Thank you

Comment: Please provide more information about your wiring and hardware. We don't like to speculate about things like this. What does "jump to" mean?

Comment: Wiring is a 12/2. I don't know what you mean by hardware. I have a 100 amp breaker box. Jump means power is not splitting up into the two 120 circuit breaker it's going directly into one 120 circuit breaker. So when testing each breaker when main is on one 120 reads 0 and the second one reads 240 instead of each one having a test reading of 120 each

Comment: Your hardware is your panel type/brand, your breaker type, etc. Don't leave us guessing. Please revise to put all that information in your question. Photos are great. :)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please consider taking the [tour] and [edit] your post to include clear pictures of your panel, including its labeling. There are several possibilities, one of which has to do with where the other end of your voltmeter / multimeter is connected

Comment: Just in case -- it's hard to tell with the amount of details given -- If I understand from your description, this could be a power supply problem.  Have you contacted your power provider?   Do so ASAP.   If what you are saying is you have 240 volts on 110 volt circuits tell them that.

Comment: Picture would help a lot!

Comment: No I haven't contacted the power company yet but will ASAP Thank you rrauenza

Comment: Are you sure you are testing correctly?  If you place the "common" voltmeter lead on a power lug, that reading would be expected.

Comment: What points are you measuring voltage between?